# load image by "imagenamed" method in xcode 6

Tags: ios

I feel this should be a typical question, but haven't found any answer yet. Basically what I'm trying to do is load image by imagenamed method for iPhone, iPad, Retina and non-Retina. What I'm doing is

1. Add 4 images into image assets. (`image_name~iphone.png`, `image_name@2x~iphone.png`, `image_name~ipad.png` and `image_name@2x~ipad.png`) and set the image set name to "image_name".
2. In the code I just call `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"]` to load for different devices and resolutions.

The problem is the edges of the image look distorted for non-Retina devices like iPad mini and iPad 2. I'm thinking maybe it is not picking the right image for the non-Retina devices. Is there anything wrong with my naming conventions? Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: It should use the right image for the right device. Try setting your `UIImageView` its `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`. Can you send a screenshot of "image_name" in your image assets?

Comment: You might want to open up the images in an editor and draw a different colour box on each one so that you can identify them in the application during your debugging.

Comment: @KevinHirsch thanks for the reply, I tried to set the UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit, but still the same thing. =(

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your image naming conventions. Can you edit your question and send a screenshot of "image_name" in your image assets, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the interruption. It ends up to be a problem of the image.=P